# Not able to install Google Chome latest version on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, google-chrome, linux-mint

I want Google Chrome latest version on my Linux Mint system.

When I am trying to install Chrome on my Linux Mint system it gives me error like this:

> Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0)

Now when I am trying to install "libfontconfig1" dependency, again it gives me error:

> Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: fontconfig-config (= 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2)

At last when I am trying to install "fontconfig-config" dependency, again it gives me error:

> Error: Breaks existing package 'libfontconfig1' dependency fontconfig-config (= 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
sudo apt-get purge libfontconfig1
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install font
```